# How to change the root for links in html

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, radix

I was hoping that adding a `<base href="http://www.myweb.com/newroot/" />` tag would cause that links like `/link` would point to `http://www.myweb.com/newroot/link` instead of `http://www.myweb.com/link`.

Soon I realized it does not work that way and it only applies to hrefs which do not start with `/`.

But is there any way to achieve the behavior I expected before (without the use of JavaScript)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

links with a leading / always point to the root/domain. This is a client-side issue, i think there is no other solution than dropping the / of using js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML `base` element like you did. but instead to linking to `/link` try simply linking to `link`

Comment: I need to distinguish between the two forms. The 'link' form I need to point to relative subfolder, the '/link' to point to my redefined root.